# VIM don't make = be ? in regex

Tags: regex, vim

In Vim, equals (`=`) is the same as question mark (`?`) in a regex, as in:

`a?` is same as `a=` is same as `a 0 or 1 times`.

When you search with `/v` on you have to escape `=`. I don't want to have to escape `=`, because that's not a standard regex character. Can I make Vim treat `=` as literal in regex search mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this when you have enabled `very magic` mode by using `\v`.  This specifically asks Vim to treat `=` as a special character.  In other modes besides `very magic` it is treated as a literal and not a special character.

Comment: Thank you. I keep forgetting how bad Vim is. I search with `\v` which is the Right Way™ in Vim so I don't have to escape groups `(`, etc, when I want to use them. It sucks that Vim has its own regex flavors that no one else uses that there's no way to avoid.

Comment: I agree that it sucks.  Vi(m) was here first, and it is very confusing that later languages decided not to adopt vim's flavor of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The very point of \v is to make everything "very magic", so why not just use \m?